# How to select and order an extracted column in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a query builder to select all users created in the last 12 months

```
$range = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(1);
            $countUser = DB::table('users')
                        ->select(DB::raw('month(created_at) as getMonth'),
                                 DB::raw('year(created_at) as getYear'), 
                                 DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value'))
                        ->where('created_at', '>=', $range)
                        ->groupBy('getMonth','getYear')
                        ->orderBy('getMonth', 'ASC')
                        ->get();
```

This query works fine with MySQL, However, when I deploy it on Heroku which runs with PostgreSQL database it returns an error

> column "getMonth" does not exist LINE 1: ...end date)", "extract(year from created_at)" order by "getMonth"... ^ (SQL: select extract(month from created_at) as getMonth, extract(year from created_at) as getYear, COUNT(*) as value from "users" where "created_at" >= 2019-10-01 03:16:43 group by "extract(month from created_at)", "extract(year from created_at)" order by "getMonth" asc)

I tried to search and figured out that postgest has a different statement to get month and year in `created_at` column and I change my code to this and it also returns the error not found column `getMonth` for the `GroupBy()`

```
$range = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(1);
            $countUser = DB::table('users')
                        ->select(DB::raw('extract(month from created_at) as getMonth'),
                            DB::raw('extract(year from created_at) as getYear'),
                            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value'))
                        ->where('created_at', '>=', $range)
                        ->groupBy('getMonth','getYear')
                        ->orderBy('getMonth', 'ASC')
                        ->get();
```

Does PostgreSQL have any naming rules to set a name for a selected column or does it has any way to solve my problem?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: @WaytoDeveloper it is?  do you have a link to information about getMonth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use mixed-case aliases in postgresql, they have to be quoted.  Use get_month instead of getMonth, or use `AS "getMonth"` and `groupBy('"getMonth"',...`